# iPhone: How to restore and update without using iTunes or iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, restore, setup

I decided to delete an existing iCloud account on my new iPhone SE which my deceased mom left me. After successful deletion, i changed password and forgot it. Now "iPhone is disabled connect to iTunes" is he only display i see. But whenever I connect to iTunes and software update begins to download, it pauses. And instead of resuming the download, it stops even if it is 99 % done and starts all over again.

I'm unable to pause download on iTunes and this is killing me because the file is too large for me to afford mobile data or Wi-Fi for.

Please help me with any other alternative aside using iTunes or iCloud. i have no iCloud account on my iPhone SE and i deleted the existing one.

**How can I restore and update my iPhone SE without using iCloud or iTunes?**

Comment: Hate to say this, but I can't think of any way to do a restore/update of an iPhone with either iTunes or iCloud. Have you considered going to an Apple Store to do the restore, since they have free wifi?

Answer (score -1):

Restore iPhone not available without iTunes. 
You can only do Factory Reset without iTunes.